# Data from HTML to Javascript Google Spredsheets sidebar

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to write a sidebar menu, but I am having trouble getting the user input. The end goal is to take the user input and create a new sheet. To start if I see the user input in the log that would be great.

Thanks,

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UrhuyDmoaRhUbyq9Usm8FVaA6N3wvxW2A_uzAMeag44/edit?usp=sharing

Google Script

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  function onOpen() {
    var menu = [
    {name:"Setup Markbook", functionName:"firstTime"},

    ];
    ss.addMenu("MarkBook", menu);
}


function firstTime(){

    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var html =  HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('firstTime.html').setTitle('Setup Markbook');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);

}


function onSuccess() {     

       var className = document.getElementById('className').innerHTML = item;
        Logger.log(className);

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

  </head>
  <body>

     <div>
        <form name="firstTime" id="firstTime">

            Class Name:
            <br/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="***Year 9 ***" name="className">


      </form>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()" />
    <button onclick="google.spript.run.submitData();" >Save</button>

    <input type="button" value="Close Sidebar" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
 </div>
```

Comment: I can't see anything in the link you have provided, just the blank spreadsheet. Maybe [this tutorial](http://www.encodedna.com/javascript/how-to-read-data-from-html-table-using-javascript.htm) could help you to start with the extracting of data from spreadsheet, if I understood your point. Also, to learn more about sheets api, you can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts)

Comment: Yes the spreadsheet is not the issue and currently does not need any cells filled. The issue is the sidebar menu, I've been searching for months and haven't been able to find a solution.  Please see the script attached above.